# header overlapping other body elements;

Tags: css

Trying to give some margin between div.header and div.Main_2, but the div.header overlaps div.Main_2 because of "position: fixed;". 
I tried with "margin-bottom: 50px;", but it still remains superimposed.

**Is there any way to make the margin with the least possible code, without take out the "position: fixed;"?**

CSS:

```
.header {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4eb151;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="Main_1">
    <div class="header">
       MyHeader
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Main_2">
    <input type="file" name="BttFile" accept="" required class="PathInputFile">
    <input type="submit" class="SubmitStyle_1" value="Upload" name="Upload">
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: MyHeader-Img]

Comment: Just set top padding to your `body` equal to the height of `header`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a container with `position: fixed | absolute`. Set in the parent the `height` to a fixed number and `position: relative` for it so the space is reserved.

```css
.header {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4eb151;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
 height: 42px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="Main_1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">MyHeader</div>
  </div>
  <div class="Main_2">
    <input type="file" name="BttFile" accept="" required class="PathInputFile">
    <input type="submit" class="SubmitStyle_1" value="Upload" name="Upload">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best solution for what i really want to do! The other ones works too, but this one fits better in my project. TY

Answer (score 3):

Since [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything_(42)) is "*the answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything*", try setting `margin-top:42px;` to your class `Main_2`

```css
.header {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4eb151;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.Main_2 {
  margin-top:42px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Main_1">
    <div class="header">
       MyHeader
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Main_2">
    <input type="file" name="BttFile" accept="" required class="PathInputFile">
    <input type="submit" class="SubmitStyle_1" value="Upload" name="Upload">
  </div>
</body>
```

Or, as suggested in the comment by @KarlenKishmiryan you can also use padding on your body:

```css
.header {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #333333;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #4eb151;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

body {
  padding-top:42px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="Main_1">
    <div class="header">
       MyHeader
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="Main_2">
    <input type="file" name="BttFile" accept="" required class="PathInputFile">
    <input type="submit" class="SubmitStyle_1" value="Upload" name="Upload">
  </div>
</body>
```